# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just trying to test my models out, but this error keeps popping up, i've checked out my code, i can't find the bug. *wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4)*

show_movie.spec.rb

```
it "Shows Flop! if total gross is under $30000000" do

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 25000000.00))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text("Flop!")

    end

    it "Shows total gross if total gross is between $30000000 and $50000000" do

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 40000000.00))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text("$40,000,000.00")

    end

    it "Shows Hot! if total gross is higher than $50000000" do

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 60000000.00))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text("Hot!")

    end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h3>Rating</h3>
    <p>
      <%= format_total_gross(@movie) %>
      </p>
```

movie_helpers.rb

```
def format_total_gross(movie)
    if movie.flop?
        content_tag[:strong, "Flop!"]
    elsif movie.hot?
        content_tag[:strong, "Hot!"]
    else
        movie.attachment.thumb
    end
end
```

movie.rb model

def flop?
        total_gross.blank? || total_gross < 30000000
    end

```
def hot?
    total_gross > 50000000
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `content_tag`, use parentheses, not brackets

```
content_tag(:strong, "Flop!")
```

Here are the [RAILS API docs on content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag).